# HTML5 Audio Playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, playlist

I'm trying to build an HTML5 audio player, my main problem is scrolling through tracks.  I have built a JSON file containing my tracks with titles and other information.  Here is the html code.

```
<audio>
   <source src="" id="oggSource" type="audio/ogg" />
   <source src="" id="mp3Source" type="audio/mpeg" />
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<br/>

<input type="button" value="<<" onclick="">
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="playPause()">
<input type="button" value=">>" onclick="playNextSongOnClick()"><br/>
<input type="button" value="Duration" onclick="duration()"><input type="button" value="currentTime" onclick="currentTime()"><br/>
```

here is my javascript

```
function initiate_AudioPlayer(){
  var song = 0;
  $("#oggSource").attr("src","audio/"+playlist.songs[song].source+".ogg");
  $("#mp3Source").attr("src","audio/"+playlist.songs[song].source+".mp3");  
}

function playPause() {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  if (audio.paused){audio.play();}
  else {audio.pause();}
}

function playNextSongOnClick(){
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  $("#oggSource").attr("src", "audio/song2.ogg");
  $("#mp3Source").attr("src", "audio/song2.mp3");

  audio.pause();
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}

function duration(){
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  alert (audio.duration);
}

function currentTime(){
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  alert (audio.currentTime);
}

$('document').ready(initiate_AudioPlayer);
```

In Safari audio plays when I press play, but won't play another track after.
When I click on the "duration" button, "NaN" pops up, so I assume that Safari is not loading the file.

In Firefox I get the opposite problem.  The first track returns a duration of "NaN" but when I click on the "play next track" button, an actual duration value is returned and the track plays.

In Chrome everything works awesome!  I haven't tested in IE9.

Should I be buffering or unloading files or something like that?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.